# Connecting to Azure Blob Storage from R with SAS-URI "only"

Tags: r, azure-blob-storage

I am trying to connect to Azure Blob Storage using the "AzureStor" package. I only have a SAS URI to my storage account.

Get the message: "Bad Request (HTTP 400). Failed to complete Storage Services operation. Message: InvalidUri. The requested URI does not represent any resource on the server."

In the Microsoft Azure Storage Explorer the URI works.

This is my code

```
library(AzureStor)

end_point <- blob_endpoint("https://storagename.blob.core.windows.net/myname/",
                      sas = "sv=2018-xxxx0SCdi8aO6%2FyYzT0dHHPca0KhyNrFHtE%3D")

list_blob_containers(end_point)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you're getting this error is because you're trying to use a blob container URL to list blob containers.

Please try by changing your code to something like:

```
library(AzureStor)

end_point <- blob_endpoint("https://storagename.blob.core.windows.net/",
                      sas = "sv=2018-xxxx0SCdi8aO6%2FyYzT0dHHPca0KhyNrFHtE%3D")

list_blob_containers(end_point)
```

Please do note that listing blob containers using SAS token would require you to get an [`Account SAS`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/create-account-sas) token with `list` permission at the `Service` level. At the very least, your SAS token should have:

Signed Service (`ss`): Blob Service (`b`)

Signed Resource Types (`srt`): Service (`s`)

Signed Permission (`sp`): List (`l`)

If you do not have these, your list blob containers operation will fail.

Comment: Thanks, I guess you´ve identified the problem(s). Think I need to get this Account SAS. Will see how to obtain this. Thxs